# If $f $ is differentiable at $c$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}=f(c)-cf'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}=f(c)-cf'(c).$$

This is from a first course real analysis class we Are working on continuity and differentiablility.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{xf(c)-cf(c)+cf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}\\=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{xf(c)-cf(c)}{x-c}-\lim_{x\to c} \frac{cf(x)-cf(c)}{x-c}$$

Comment: im getting a + instead of a - on the last equation where you break up the limit

Comment: @user110976 Fixed ty.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For every $x\ne c$,
$$\frac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}=f(c)-c\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

Comment: Is that obvious?

Comment: @EricAm Yes. $ $

Answer (score 0):

Let $g:\mathbb R-\{c\}\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto\dfrac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}.$

Then we are to check $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(x).$

Note $c$ is a limit point of the respective domain $\mathbb R-\{c\}.$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\\=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{xf(c)-cf(x)}{x-c}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{xf(c)-cf(c)-cf(x)+cf(c)}{x-c}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{xf(c)-cf(c)}{x-c}-\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{cf(x)-cf(c)}{x-c}\\=f(c)-c\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\\=f(c)-cf'(c)$